# Do I need to pull the full user list to get a random user from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

For simplicity purposes lets say I have a Firebase scheme that looks something like:

- Userlist

  - User1

    - Age - 22
    - Gender - M
  - User2

    - Age - 26
    - Gender - M
  - User3

    - Age - 20
    - Gender - F

Let's say I wanted to get a random user from that list within a desired age range and a desired gender. Right now  I am pulling the full userlist, filtering out the ones who don't match my preferences and then getting a random user from those that match on the client side. This has worked fine for a small number of users, but what if  I have 10,000 users?

Is there any way to accomplish this without downloading a full list of ALL the users as this is very bandwidth heavy. With a relational database it would be easy to just use a where clause but since I can't with Firebase I assume I have to do everything client side which means retrieving the full data list. What is the correct approach to this to minimize bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

One solution (and, I think, at present, the only solution) is to keep a separate list in your database of just usernames ("User1", "User2", ...). Then to get a random user, retrieve the list of usernames and take a random item from it. Then retrieve the corresponding full user from the full user list.

Comment: That's indeed what I would do. The only difference is that I would create separate lists (at Firebase we often call them *indexex*) for each filter. So a `menList` list, with just the ids of men, `womenList` with just the women and if needed `teenList` with just the teens, etc.

Comment: Although this is a viable solution, are there any plans to implement easier ways to do things like getting just the first level of a Firebase path?

To me it seems inflexible to require the creation of new database structures each time you want to view the data in a different way.